# Как работает Retrofit на android?

Tags: android, retrofit

Здравствуйте.

Объясните пожалуйста как работает Retrofit. Есть страница c json. В android подключил Retrofit,  okhttp, converter-gson. 
json такой:

```
{"1":
    {"id":101,
     "item":"NameItem1",
     "itemId":"1",
     "name":"NameName",
     "img":"http:cccccc.jpg"},
"2":
    {"id":102,
     "item":"NameItem2",
     "itemId":"3",
     "name":"NameName",
     "img":"http:cccccc.jpg"},
"3":
    {"id":103,
     "item":"NameItem3",
     "itemId":"2",
     "name":"NameName",
     "img":"http:sddfsssds.jpg"}}
```

1) Во всех примерах пишут что нужно создать POJO класс эквивалентный JSON. Пользуюсь http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ В моем случае это будет один MyClass. в котором будут переменные Id, item, itemId и т.д. с геттерами и сеттарми. Или это будет несколько классов если вставить весь json?

2) Как работает get запрос в retrofit?

```
public interface APIService {
    // Ниже пишу название файла с json?
    @GET("list")
    // В Call передаю просто MyClass? Или список из MyClass? 
   // В getData в аргументах перечисляю все переменные которые в MyClass? 
    Call<List<MyClass>> getData(@Query("id") int id, @Query("item") String item ...);
}
```

Comment: Это не будет List. У вас объект, а не массив. Это будет какой-то ваш класс, у которого будут свойства, в которые надо будет записать ваши объекты MyClass, причем свойства эти будут иметь @SerializedName("1"), @SerializedName("2")... впрочем вы можете написать свой десериализатор и превратить этот json в List... Сервер ваш? Может проще на сервере поправить...

Comment: @YuraIvanov . Значит 2 вариант в MyClass в котором будут прописано @SerializedName("1"), @SerializedName("2")... а в Классах 1, 2, 3 уже будет прописаны переменные id, item и т.д. тогда Call<MyClass>  будет? А что в getData тогда прийдет? И как до id, item и т.д. добраться? При таком подходе если добавится 4 пункт нужно будет дописывать новый класс 4 и в MyClass добавлять @SerializedName("4") в ручную? Сервер не мой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это будет два класса

MyClassPack:

```
public class MyClassPack {

    @SerializedName("1")
    @Expose
    public MyClass _1;

    @SerializedName("2")
    @Expose
    public MyClass _2;

    @SerializedName("3")
    @Expose
    public MyClass _3;
}
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    public int id;

    @SerializedName("item")
    @Expose
    public String item;

    @SerializedName("itemId")
    @Expose
    public String itemId;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("img")
    @Expose
    public String img;
}
```

и сменить получаемый класс, в параметрах указываете необходимые параметры для запроса на сервер, не могу точно ответить, так как нет информации как вы получаете даннные, к примеру: список получаю с урла - http://some.com/list?id=5

```
public interface APIService {

    @GET("list")
    Call<MyClassPack> getData(@Query("id") int id);
}
```

Если хотите один класс, а не два - должен приходить массив

Comment: Чтобы приходил массив нужно убрать 1, 2, 3, в которые вложены  id, item и т.д.?

Comment: чтобы приходил массив нужен такой джейсон: 

    [
    {"id":101,
     "item":"NameItem1",
     "itemId":"1",
     "name":"NameName",
     "img":"http:cccccc.jpg"},
    {"id":102,
     "item":"NameItem2",
     "itemId":"3",
     "name":"NameName",
     "img":"http:cccccc.jpg"},
    {"id":103,
     "item":"NameItem3",
     "itemId":"2",
     "name":"NameName",
     "img":"http:sddfsssds.jpg"}
    ]